# jQuery draggable: distance and delay at same time does not work

Tags: jquery, draggable

I want to use the **distance and delay** parameter of a **draggable** at the same time. The goal is, that I do not need to move the mouse to start the drag effect, but it should start after 500ms to prevent unintentional moves.

This seems not to work. Here is an example for you to test:

```
$('.cube').draggable(
{
   distance: 0,
   delay: 500,
   start : function()
   {
    $('.cube').css('background', 'green');
   },
   stop: function()
   {
    $('.cube').css('background', 'red');
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/2392/

As it is, if you click without moving, it will not drag. When you remove the delay option, it will drag without moving but immediatly.

So is this a **bug** or a **feature** and is there any workaround?

Regards

Claus

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature, you can refer to this link http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-delay

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  delay: 300
});
```

Setting delay to 0 will avoid the lag..

Answer (score 0):

This occurred cause the delay not start all the function same time, I believe this a bug, however, you can use other function to increase your code.

```
$('.cube').mousedown(function()
{
        $(this).css('background', 'green');
})

$('.cube').mouseup(function()
{
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
})
```

This work very well, I hope this code help you.

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-delay